# SQL query find rows that share the same tags

Tags: sql, csv, tags

Let's see if someone can help me...
On a product page, I have to show related products. These products are related depending on their tags. For example my product (ID 23) has the following tags: cooking, noodles, healthy.

What I have to do, is a SQL query, that search for products that have the tags "cooking, noodles, healthy" but separately

First search for all the products that have "cooking" in their tags, then look for other products to have "noodles" , and finally "healthy".

The products shown have to be in order: first show all products that have "cooking" in the tags column, then "noodles" and lastly "healthy". Important, the products do not have to be repeated.

This is the order I hope to get: ID: 25, 25, 40, 43, 46

This is the database

| ID | Tags | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 23 | cooking, noodles, healthy | Noodles Hot white pepper |
| 25 | cooking, noodles, healthy | Soap of noodles |
| 35 | cooking, noodles, healthy | Noodles with carrots |
| 40 | food, noodles, ketchup | New Noodles with ketchup |
| 43 | apple, cook, healthy | Apple with sugar |
| 46 | banana, cook, healthy | Banana with sugar |

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: use ranking with full text search

Comment: Could you give me an example? The truth would not know how to do it. Thanks for your answer

Comment: which dbms are you using?

Comment: You should fix your database model so you are **not** storing multiple values in a single column.

Answer (score 1):

The way you store your data makes things unnecessarily suboptimal. You should not have multiple strings stored in a single column; instead, there should be another table to store the relation between products and tags, with each tuple should on a separate row.

For your current design, you can do:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where 
    ',' || tags || ',' like '%,cooking,%'
    or ',' || tags || ',' like '%,noodles,%'
    or ',' || tags || ',' like '%,healthy,%'
order by 
    case
        when ',' || tags || ',' like '%,cooking,%' then 1
        when ',' || tags || ',' like '%,noddles,%' then 2
        else 3
    end,
    id
```

This uses standard string concatenation operator `||`: you might need to adapt that to your actual database.

Some databases have built-in functions to search a CSV list. If, for example, you are running MySQL:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where 
    find_in_set('cooking', tags)
    or find_in_set('noodles', tags)
    or find_in_set('healthy', tags)
order by 
    case
        when find_in_set('cooking', tags) then 1
        when find_in_set('noodles', tags) then 2
        else 3
    end,
    id
```

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation and for the query it works perfect. Only i have one issue. I need to show all those records except the one with ID 25 for example. What should I add in the query?

Comment: @BraiKaler: use the `where` clause. `where id <> 25 and (find_in_set() or ...)`